# How to prevent 'check disk for defects' to run

Tags: 19.04, badblocks, disk-check

I had some bad blocks within my hard drive lately but I was able to repair them . I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Hard drive ( which is empty ) but I don't get the Grub Interface thing , it automatically runs ' check disk for defects ' . How can I prevent this program to start at startup ?

Answer (score 0):

Preventing a check for disk defects would be... bad.

Ubuntu only runs [fsck](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/fsck.8.html) on its own if it finds something wrong in the drive(s). If you had bad blocks in a drive, run a [SMART](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) check to see if the problem is growing, and budget for a new drive, soon.

Comment: `fsck` can be configured to run every boot if you want I think...